# MySQL Query to get each sales per month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in Mysql. I want to regroup and count the Number of Orderid per month for each customer. If there is no order, I would like to add 0.

Customer Table

```
CustomerID              
    1
    2
    3
```

Order Table

```
OrderId  CustomerID      Date
1          1           2022-01-02
2          1           2022-01-04
3          2           2022-02-03
4          2           2022-03-03
```

Expect results

```
 CustomerID       Date       CountOrderID
    1            2022-01         2 
    2            2022-01         1
    3            2022-01         0
    1            2022-02         0 
    2            2022-02         1
    3            2022-02         0
    1            2022-03         0 
    2            2022-03         1
    3            2022-03         0
```

How I can do this in Mysql?

Comment: `(2, '2022-01', 1)` - where this is taken from?

Answer (score 1):

you can reduce the number of cte's I added more here to explain the steps:

- first you need the format year and month, for that I used `DATE_FORMAT()` function
- since you need to have all the combination of dates and the year month you need a `cross join`. This will produce all the distinct dates with all the distinct customer id's. In other words all the pairs between dates and customer id
- once you have a table with all the combinations you need to pass the actual data with the `left join` this will produce null where you actually don't have rows and hence will produce 0 when the count is performed
- the last step is simply `count` function

```
with main as (
    
    select distinct DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') as year_month from order
    ),
    
    calendar as (
    
    select * from customer
    cross join main
    ),
    joining_all as (
    
    select 
    calendar.*,
    order. OrderId
    left join order
    on calendar.CustomerID = order.CustomerID
    and calendar.year_month = DATE_FORMAT(order.date,'%Y-%m')
    )
    
    select 
    CustomerID,
    year_month as Date,
    count(OrderId) as CountOrderID
    from joining_all
    group by 1,2
```

- maybe the shorter version can work with the code below. if runs into syntax you can use the one above

```
with main as (
select distinct DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') as year_month from order
cross join customer
)
 select 
    main.CustomerID,
    main.year_month as Date,
    count(order.OrderId) as CountOrderID
    from main
    left join order
    on main.CustomerID = order.CustomerID
    and main.year_month = DATE_FORMAT(order.date,'%Y-%m')
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT customer.CustomerID,
       year_month.y_m AS `Date`,
       COUNT(order.OrderId) AS CountOrderID
FROM customer
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m') AS y_m
    FROM order 
    ) AS year_month
LEFT JOIN order ON order.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID
               AND DATE_FORMAT(order.`date`, '%Y-%m') = year_month.y_m
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

If `order` table does not contains for some year and month then according row won't present in the output. If you need in it then you'd generate calendar table instead of `year_month` subquery.